# Swf-video replay in the Chrome incorrectly

Tags: google-chrome, flash, replay

I have a such problem as incorrect replay a swf-video in the Chrome.

In details:
I have the task for playing the swf-video in new window when user clicks a button on a page. As a result the swf plays only when browser has no files for video in the cache (opening video in the first time). But when I try to play swf-video repeatedly by the button click, video is not shown and audio is playing only.

I don't have any idea for fixed this problem. Can anybody help me?

Characteristics software: 
Chrome - version 18.0.1025.142, swf - Shockwave Flash Object, version 10.0.45.2.
Video is a record from a computer which says how to use the my site.